# Stored proceedure not returning all rows when it should. Whats wrong?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

In the Ques Table, some of the earlier added rows have AdminLangID column's value as NULL. The following SP should return those rows too but it's not. What is wrong? What condition do I need to add so it returns *ALL* the rows? I just manually set the AdminLangID of some rows, then it would return those, but not the ones with AdminLangID as NULL. I want it to return those rows as well. What do I need to change? This SP has been used to bind a grid on my page and the grid is rendering ONLY those rows that have AdminLangeID as NOT NULL.

```
BEGIN
 IF @QuesID = 0
  SET @QuesID =NULL
SELECT     FQ.QuesID, FQ.Ques,QuesAns
FROM         Admin.Ques FQ

INNER JOIN Admin.Lang AL ON AL.AdminLangID=FQ.AdminLangID
WHERE   FQ.QuesID = Coalesce(@QuesID,QuesID)
END
```

Comment: wrong title. It returns exactl all rows it should. Title indicates a SQL side issue (rows getting lost in transfer) instead of an "i dont know sql" style of question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *I just manually set the AdminLangID of some rows, then it wud return those but not the ones with AdminLangID as NULL.*

The inner join to Admin.Lang means the query will only return rows that have AdminLangID filled in. Change it to an outer join to make it return rows with null AdminLangID:

```
ALTER PROC [Schema2].[GetQues]    
(
 @QuesID int
 )
AS
BEGIN
 IF @QuesID = 0
  SET @QuesID =NULL
SELECT     FQ.QuesID, FQ.Ques,QuesAns as QuesAns,FQ.QuesAns[Answers], FQT.QuesType ,FQ.QuesTypeID, FQ.QuesParentID, FQ.Active, FQ.AdminLangID,AL.TelerikLang, AL.LangID
FROM         Admin.Ques FQ
LEFT OUTER JOIN Admin.QuesTypes FQT ON FQT.QuesTypeID=FQ.QuesTypeID
LEFT OUTER JOIN Admin.Lang AL ON AL.AdminLangID=FQ.AdminLangID
WHERE   FQ.QuesID = Coalesce(@QuesID,QuesID)
END
```